# How to flatten List of List into a new object List in Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to flatten a List of List into new object list with Java 8 Stream API.

```
    Public Class Currency {
     String companyId;
     List<CurrencyValue> currencyValues;
     }

  


   Public Class CurrencyValue {
      String currencyCode;
      Date currencyDate;
      Bigdecimal CurrencyValue;
   }


     public Class MemberCurrency {
       String company_id;
       String currencyCode;
       Date currencyDate;
       Bigdecimal CurrencyValue;

      }
```

I have a  `List<Currency>` in which each currency has list of CurrencyValues and i want  to create from it a new `List<MemberCurrency>`

Comment: Yes it probably is. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried all of possible answers on same subject but i never seen field or fields from parent list flattened and mapped and included in  new object list. @Pablo Andrés Rodas Giraldo 's answer is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your model, you will need to flatMap your list of currencies to get your currencyValues, but first, mapping the currency values to create the Member currency, something like this:

```
currencies.stream()
                .flatMap(c -> c.currencyValues.stream()
                        .map(cv -> new MemberCurrency(
                                c.companyId, cv.currencyCode, cv.currencyDate, cv.currencyValue)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another thing that I would suggest is to add access modifiers to the fields and the corresponding getters an setters, apart from the parametrized constructor that I had to add to MemberCurrency class.

```
        public MemberCurrency(String company_id, String currencyCode, Date currencyDate, BigDecimal currencyValue) {
            this.company_id = company_id;
            this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
            this.currencyDate = currencyDate;
            this.currencyValue = currencyValue;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Pablo Andrés Rodas Giraldo . It worked.